# removing textfield in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this problem using javascript whenever I create row and try to remove one, the last row can only removed. here's my javascript

```
 <script>

 function createinput(){

var field_area = document.getElementById('fields');
var num = document.forms["zxc"]["set"].value;
for(var count=1;count<=num;count++){

var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");
var td2 = document.createElement("td");
var td3 = document.createElement("td");
var td4 = document.createElement("td");
var label = document.createElement("label");
var label2 = document.createElement("label");
var label3 = document.createElement("label");
var label4 = document.createElement("label");
var input = document.createElement("input");
var input2 = document.createElement("input");
var input3 = document.createElement("input");
var input4 = document.createElement("input");

input.id = 'qty[]';
input.name = 'qty[]';
input.type = "text";
input.className = "form-control";
input2.id = 'unit[]';
input2.name = 'unit[]';
input2.type = "text";
input2.className = "form-control";
input3.id = 'articles[]';
input3.name = 'articles[]';
input3.type = "text";
input3.className = "form-control";
input4.id = 'serial_number[]';
input4.name = 'serial_number[]';
input4.type = "text";
input4.className = "form-control";
tr.appendChild(td);
tr.appendChild(td2);
tr.appendChild(td3);
tr.appendChild(td4);
td.appendChild(label);
td2.appendChild(label2);
td3.appendChild(label3);
td4.appendChild(label4);
label.appendChild(input);
label2.appendChild(input2);
label3.appendChild(input3);
label4.appendChild(input4);

field_area.appendChild(tr);

var removalLink = document.createElement('a');
removalLink.className = "remove";
removalLink.onclick = function(){
    field_area.removeChild(tr); 
}

removalLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Remove Field'));
tr.appendChild(removalLink);

}
}
</script>
```

And here's my HTML.

```
<form name="zxc" method="post">
<label><input type="text" id="set" name="set"></label><input type="button" onClick="createinput()" value="create" ></form>
 <table width="800" id="fields">
  <tr>
   <th>Quantity</th>
   <th>Unit</th>
   <th>Article</th>
   <th>Serial</th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I used a for loop to control how many rows can be created.. I can't solve the problem in removing each rows. I need help please!

Comment: Your question is bit vague as the code is huge...

Comment: IDs have to be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD** Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/5TWsv/2/.

You are creating functions in a loop. They will point the same variable. You need

```
var makeHandler = function(row) { 
    return function () {
        field_area.removeChild(row);
    }
};

...
for(...) {
...
removalLink.onclick = makeHandler(tr);
```

Then `num` is of type string. You need to convert it to a number

```
 var num = parseInt(document.forms["zxc"]["set"].value);
```

And ensure `num` is actually a number

```
 if(!isNaN(num)) {
```

And finally **IDs have to be unique within document!** That's why it is called an "identifier".

Comment: I don't have any problem regarding with my IDs.. here's the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5TWsv/)

Comment: You do have problems with ids :) They are duplicated making your code invalid. But the problem with deletion comes from so called "infamous loop problem". As I have written functions, created in a loop, will share the same variables unless you create a closure.